# user names in comments should not count toward the total characters

Tags: feature-request

I can understand that there is a minimum number of characters (to prevent spam)

but at the same time I sometimes want to include a deal of information into my comments, and end up short by a few characters, and it usually ends up being when responding directly to users that have longer names.

the system already understands to look up names when an "@" is entered into the comment box, so maybe having the system ignore the "@", and the characters that follow (unless it does not resolve to a user name)

this is a lot more feasible then another similar request that ignores all "`" marks, but when I consider the abuse of that it just makes my head spin.

Comment: I thought you only needed the first 3 characters (or enough to make it unique on the page) of a username for it to link/notify, so couldn't you just shorten the username in those instances where this is an issue?

Answer (score 2):

If this matters that much to you, then you're using comments too much. Is the difference between 585 characters and 600 characters so great that it is absolutely essential to getting your point across?

Comment: granted some times I can be long winded/verbose in my comments, but I also try to add detail/clarifications to my comments that might in some cases over the top, but in others given needed information on the given `post` (question/answer) at hand. though when I see that my characters are almost up (within 100 or so) I do give a good read over the comment, and try to trim if I can.